# Should Ashkenazim say 'מוריד הטל' in Israel?

Tags: halacha, minhag, shemoneh-esrei, nusach-ashkenaz

The Rema (114:3) brings the Tur who says that Ashkenazim do not say 'מוריד הטל' in the amidah:

> "Us, the Ashkenazim, do not commemorate the 'טל' [i.e. say 'מוריד
>   הטל'], not in the summer days nor in the rainy season..."

Is it considered 'minhag eretz Yisrael' to say מוריד הטל and should Ashkenazim forgo the psak of the Rema and say מוריד הטל in Israel?

(This question is inspired by a conversation I had with a fellow Jew who said that for Ashkenazim who don't say 'מוריד הטל' in Israel it is as if they have not said Amidah - I believe he was bringing the opinion of Rav Shlomo Zalman Auerbach)

Comment: Why would you assume they shouldn't? Presumably, the Rema was ruling based on the Ashkenazic custom in his locale. If someone was in a location with a different ruling, they would follow the ruling of that location.

Comment: There is a distinction between publicly following the minhag hamakom and individually. Someone davening minhag ashkenaz, When davening with Sephardim, they still daven the silent amidah with minhag Ashkenaz. In the face of 'minhag yisrael', does this change in any case? I was told that, in being shliyach tzibbur, despite an ashkenazi minhag not to say morid hatal, one would say it for the tzibbur in Israel, during amidah repetition, regardless of your personal minhag (i.e. what you say for silent amidah)

Comment: FWIW, I daven Nusach Ashkenaz (live in U.S.) and say *Morid Hatal*. I'm not suggesting that what I'm doing is correct. However, I do it as when the conversion begins (1st day Pesach) it helps me avoid the mistake of saying *Morid Hageshem* since I'm substituting something else, rather than omitting something.

Comment: What is "in this case"? Do you mean only in Israel? All Ashkenazim? I don't really understand your question. Please [edit] to clarify

Comment: Nusach Ashkenaz siddurim for Israel specifically include it. So, i didn't say it in America but i do now in Israel.

Comment: See Tashbetz (Kattan) 101, http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=19929&st=&pgnum=124